# PHP:header not redirecting

Tags: php, session, header

why working this:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ...
    if(something){
      $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['value'];
      header("Location: mypage.php");
    }
   ...
```

Why not working this:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ...
    if(something){
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result);
     $_SESSION['login'] = $row['column_value_'];
     header("Location: mypage.php");
   }
  ...
```

header not redirecting. Does anybody know a solution? Please

Comment: Are you sure that first example works?

Comment: Did you check the error log? Can you show the error message?

Comment: @Danielius Yeah, my first example working. I think the problem is when set session variable with query result in if condition.

Comment: I mean, your code does not have any additional if condition.... please write normal code with normal conditions, because it's impossible to understand what may be wrong here.

Comment: @Neodan No show error message.

Comment: You definitely have an error.
Add this code into begin of your php script:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line

```
ob_start();
```

On top of the help this might help.

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Location: mypage.php");
```

try this way it may helpful to you

Comment: It's better if you explain why your answer may solve the problem they are having, just saying 'try this' is not that helpful.